# To mean "whereas", is it acceptable to use "pendant/cependant que" instead of "tandis/alors que"?

Tags: conjonctions

In the following example, a conjuncture is used to mean "**whereas**" for comparison/contrast purposes rather than "**while**" for indicating simultaneity. Given this, which of the four is appropriate for use?

Incidentally, is "cependant que" a little too formal and out of place for use in spoken language?

---

> Les chevaux voyagent par avion **tandis qu**'on conduit une vieille voiture.
>
> Les chevaux voyagent par avion **alors qu**'on conduit une vieille voiture.

---

> Les chevaux voyagent par avion **pendant qu**'on conduit une vieille voiture.
>
> Les chevaux voyagent par avion **cependant qu**'on conduit une vieille voiture.

Comment: *Tandis que*, *alors que* and *cependant que* can be roughly translated as *whereas*. However, *cependant que* is not used a lot. *Pendant que* rather means *while*, since *pendant* expresses simultaneity.

Comment: Side note: The use of "On conduit une voiture" sounds very odd to me... I would better say "on voyage dans une vieille voiture" or something like that... "conduit" only concerns the person holding the steering wheel, so it is very odd to use it with "on", which means more than one person...

Comment: I agree with @Random, and if bothered by repeating  *voyager*, then use *rouler dans*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien que les exemples soient corrects, à l'oral, pour mettre en évidence une comparaison contrastée, un hiatus, il faut mettre l'accent sur cette différence en la mettant en exergue :

> ***Tandis qu' / alors qu' / pendant qu'*** on conduit une vieille voiture, les chevaux voyagent par avion.

On choisira l'un des trois selon l'intonation que l'on veut donner : donner de l’exagération ou au contraire manier un humour à base de litotes...

Cette inversion fonctionne mal avec *cependant* : il est moins usité de nos jours dans ce sens et il carambole *pendant* dans les exemples cités.